# Laravel Component Recognized in One file but Not Another

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I've solved  this issue, But I'm EXTREMELY confused on what's going on here, and would like someone to explain it to me for future reference.

So I have a Laravel 10 Project and my first route is a welcome page

```
Route::get('/', function () { return view('welcome'); })->name('welcome');
```

I made a Blade Component that's just a static menu. I generated it, Copy/pasted the existing menu, made a slight edit, replaced block with `<x-header-menu />` and it worked fine in the welcome view.

[image]

I then made a new php file from scratch, and in this view, The blade component was Not Recognized. When I loaded the page, It didn't work. WHAT? Code was copy/pasted from the welcome page. This view was inside a folder So

```
Views/welcome.blade.php
Vs
Views/info/info_page_1.blade.php
```

But I have other pages inside folders that use a different component that work fine. So I'm SUPER confused as to what's happening here.
(Using PhpStorm IDE btw)

[image]

Now The Weirdest thing here though, Is when I deleted info_page_1.blade.php, copy/pasted the Welcome.blade.php to info_page_1.blade.php, Then copy/pasted old info_page_1.blade.php code, It worked.

So... WHAT HAPPENED HERE? Why could the Blade Component not be found with a new file but could be found with a copy/pasted already working file, In the same location with the same name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer immediately as I switched back...

Name your file

```
info_page_1.blade.php
```

instead of

```
info_page_1.php
```

Comment: It looks like the issue was related to the file extension of your new file. In Laravel, Blade templates should have the .blade.php extension, not just .php. By naming your file info_page_1.blade.php instead of info_page_1.php, you were able to resolve the problem and have the Blade component recognized correctly.

The .blade.php extension is important because it tells Laravel that the file contains Blade syntax that needs to be processed. Without the .blade.php extension, Laravel treats the file as a regular PHP file and does not perform Blade-specific operations like component resolution.

Comment: You actually had the correct filename in your question.